# Check if at least one checkbox is checked using HTML5 only

Tags: html

I'm making a form using HTML5 validation features.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="color1" value="1" required />Green</label><br />
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="color2" value="2" required />Red</label><br />
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="color3" value="3" required />Yellow</label><br />
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="color4" value="4" required />Blue</label><br />
        <input type="submit" /><input type="reset" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need it to validate if at least one checkbox is checked.

**"Must have at least one checkbox checked."**

I found answer here:
[Jquery - check if at least one checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684434/jquery-check-if-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked)
[Check if at least one checkbox is checked using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369904/check-if-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked-using-jquery)
[Making sure at least one checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787665/making-sure-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked)
[Submit form only if at least one checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557055/submit-form-only-if-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked)

But using JavaScript, jQuery and etc.

Is possible make using HTML5 only?

Comment: User have to make a choice, right ? So, how your app will be notified of user choice without javascript or sending the data to server for verification ? So, yeah, I think it's not possible...

Comment: If you can move the inputs outside the labels, you could try my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33842776/3903374

Comment: @RickHitchcock , I will consider using your solution. Thank you very much. :-D

Answer (score 1):

It is just not possible. You have to check it via JS binding a function to `onchange` that counts the number of checkboxes checked. `required` attribute for checkboxes requires that all of them are checked (as opposite for radio ones, which only need one value checked).